# extract Lat/Lng from Geo loaction string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Geo location string as **25°9'37"N 55°13'28"E**. Using JavaScript Regex I want to extract the Lat and Lng from the above string.
Thanks.

Comment: `var res="25°9'37\"N 55°13'28\"E".match(/\d+°\d+'\d+"[NEWS]/g)`

Comment: I see a white space in between each value. you can simply do a string split and use the values right

Comment: @PranavCBalan Your suggestion worked for me. Thanks alot for the perfect solution.

Comment: @PranavCBalan it won't give latitude value indeed

Comment: @SyedFasih : glad to help

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly : i know it's not the complete solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your first row could be "25°9'37"N is the minute-format of a latitude, you probably want to extract it's values and convert to it's decimal degree representation, this enables further calculation on it. @Stormwind

According to [this](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/convert-latitude-longitude) blogpost, conversion formula is

```
//latitude formula
([LATITUDE_DEG])+([LATITUDE_MIN]/60)+([LATITUDE_SEC]/3600))*
IF [Latitude_Direction]="South" THEN -1 ELSE 1 END

//longitude
([LONGITUDE_DEG]+([LONGITUDE_MIN]/60)+([LONGITUDE_SEC]/3600))*
IF [Longitude_Direction]="West" THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
```

Regex (simple)

```
//latitude
25°9'37"N
/(\w+)°(\w+)'(\w+)"(\w+)/
`25`, `9`, `37`, `N`

//regex from @PranavCBalan also works well
/(\d+)°(\d+)'(\d)+"([NEWS])/
`25`, `9`, `37`, `N`
```

Solution for latitude (simple) - notice, this solution is error prone, as it was written within 5mins, so be careful

```
var lat_str = "25°9'37\"N"; //escaped string
lat_str = lat_str.replace('\"', '"'); //little trick
var matches = lat_str.match(/(\w+)°(\w+)'(\w+)"(\w+)/); //regexify
var lat_deg = parseInt(matches[1]); //degrees
var lat_min = parseInt(matches[2]); //minutes
var lat_sec = parseInt(matches[3]); //seconds
var lat_dir = matches[4];           //direction

var latitude = (lat_deg+(lat_min/60)+(lat_sec/3600))*(lat_dir === 'N' ? 1 : -1);

//25.160277777777775
```

Solution for longitude

```
//same as latitude (except direction check), do it as your homework
```

For more details refer to [Converting Latitude/Longitude from Degrees/Minutes/Seconds to Decimal Degrees](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/convert-latitude-longitude)

Comment: This statement "25°9'37"N is decimal degree value - not a latitude, you must convert it to Latitude" _is very erratic_. Of course it's a latitude value, with minutes and even seconds. You are partially answering something that is not asked in the question, ie. how to convert that lat/lon minute pair into decimal degrees. Maybe that's what he eventually wants, but it's not phrased that way. A minute lat is typically dd°mm.mm' (where m is 0...59.99 - and seconds aren't modern any longer) while a decimal lat is dd.dddd...°. To perform calculation on it, one uses decimal degree representation.

Comment: @Stormwind I think OP was expecting usual latitude values like `23.23232` _Using JavaScript Regex I want to extract the Lat and Lng from the above string_ OP wants to get __Lat__ from `25°9'37"N` so he needs to extract degs/mins/secs from string, then convert to degree to get latitude, agreed?

Comment: Probably what he wanted, so your solution is ok. But you should correct your very first sentence. That IS most certainly a latitude, and also the "usual" one, if any, and it is NOT a decimal degree value. They don't use decimal lat/lon's at sea, rest assured. Your first row could be "25°9'37"N is the minute-format of a latitude, you probably want to extract it's values and convert to it's decimal degree representation, this enables further calculation on it", or likewise. Just to not be so misleading, because this current one shines truly red in my eyes :-).